# Snowflake download huge data

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table on Snowplow that is huge in size (2B plus). I want to download the whole file for backup and am struggling with an easy way. I was trying to run a python script on the worksheet to do this for me in chunks (monthly data) in separate csv files. Naturally this does not really work as I cannot just save the file on the OS snowflake is using. Is there a way around so I can download the csv directly on my local system?

So far my code is as following

```
import snowflake.snowpark as snowpark
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def main(session: snowpark.Session):

    end_date = datetime(2024, 3, 1)
    current_date = datetime(2022, 2, 1)

    while current_date < end_date:
        start_month = current_date
        next_month = (current_date + timedelta(days=32)).replace(day=1).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

        myquery = f"""
        select * 
        from my_table 
        where email_created_at >= '{start_month}' AND email_created_at < '{next_month}'
        """
    
        # Execute the query and convert the result to a Pandas DataFrame
        dataframe = session.sql(myquery).to_pandas()
        
        # Define the filename based on the table name and the current month
        filename = f"myfile_{current_date.strftime('%Y_%m')}.csv"
        
        # Save the DataFrame to a CSV file
        dataframe.to_csv(filename, index=False)
        
        print(f"Data for {current_date.strftime('%Y-%m')} saved to {filename}")
        
        # Move to the next month
        current_date = current_date + timedelta(days=32)
        current_date = current_date.replace(day=1)
```

Comment: what is the problem of the script when you execute it locally?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to export a table, you can send it directly to cloud storage (like S3), or to a Snowflake stage:

```
COPY INTO s3://mybucket/unload/ from mytable storage_integration = s3_int;
-- https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-unload-s3#unloading-data-directly-into-an-s3-bucket
```

You can also export into internal stages, and `COPY INTO` also supports a query as an input (instead of a table):

```
COPY INTO @my_stage/result/data_ FROM (SELECT * FROM orderstiny)
   file_format=(format_name='myformat' compression='gzip');
-- https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-location#unloading-data-from-a-query-to-files-in-a-named-internal-stage
```

To download files to your servers from a Snowflake internal stage, you can use `GET`:

- https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/get#syntax

The Pythonic way to `COPY INTO` starting with a Dataframe is `DataFrameWriter.copy_into_location()`:

```py
# save this dataframe to a parquet file on the session stage
df = session.create_dataframe([["John", "Berry"], ["Rick", "Berry"], ["Anthony", "Davis"]], schema = ["FIRST_NAME", "LAST_NAME"])
remote_file_path = f"{session.get_session_stage()}/names.parquet"
copy_result = df.write.copy_into_location(remote_file_path, file_format_type="parquet", header=True, overwrite=True, single=True)
copy_result[0].rows_unloaded

# https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowpark/reference/python/latest/api/snowflake.snowpark.DataFrameWriter.copy_into_location
```